# "INVALID QUERY RESULT MASK" PostgreSQL through Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql

I have been trying to access a psql function using the `db.func` function.

The following is my query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION play_game(game INT, IN userid INT, IN card INT, OUT uid INT, OUT cid INT, OUT cardfile varchar(255) ) RETURNS SETOF record as
$$
DECLARE
     playorder integer;
     
     cardtype varchar(6);
     cardcolor varchar(10);
     cardvalue integer;
     
     l_cardtype varchar(6);
     l_cardcolor varchar(10);
     l_cardvalue integer;
     cardid integer;
Begin
    -- check if this is the user who has to play
    SELECT play_order INTO playorder FROM user_game WHERE user_id = userid;
    
    IF playorder = 1 THEN
        -- get card attributes
        SELECT card_type, card_color, card_value
             INTO cardtype, cardcolor, cardvalue
            FROM card
         WHERE card_id = card;
     
         -- get the attributes of the last card that was played for this game
         select c.card_id, c.card_type, c.card_color, c.card_value
           INTO cardid, l_cardtype, l_cardcolor, l_cardvalue
           FROM play_card pc, card c
           WHERE pc.card_id = c.card_id
                  AND pc.game_id = game
                  AND pc.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM play_card WHERE game_id = game);
       Begin
            -- check this is the right card to play
            IF cardcolor = l_cardcolor AND
                 cardtype = 'NOM' THEN
                INSERT INTO play_card (game_id, user_id, card_id) VALUES (game, userid, card);
                -- delete card from draw card
                DELETE FROM game_card WHERE game_id = game and card_id = card;
            END IF;
            commit;
       End;
       
       -- move play to the next player
       Begin
          IF cardtype = 'NOM' THEN
               UPDATE user_game
                        SET play_order = play_order - 1
                 WHERE game_id = game;
               
               UPDATE user_game
                        SET play_order = (SELECT count(user_id) from user_game WHERE game_id = game)
                 WHERE game_id = game;
            ELSE
                  UPDATE user_game
                           SET play_order = 1 + (SELECT count(user_id) from user_game WHERE game_id = game) - play_order
                       WHERE game_id = game;
            END IF;
       End;
       
    End if;

    -- get game state and return to Front END
  RETURN QUERY SELECT gc.user_id, gc.card_id, c.image_file FROM game_card gc, card c WHERE gc.card_id = c.card_id AND gc.game_id = game ORDER BY user_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is my javascript function

```
db.func("play_game", { gameId, userId, cardId })
    .then((results) => {
      let card = results;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("error in play_game databse function: ", error);
    });
```

I have even tried passing the parameters without the object but I get the error saying "invalid query result mask"

It also gives the following hint:
No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Please let me know what to do. Any help is appreciated. Thank you :)